# Python module installation failing

Tags: python, time, module, pip

My python wont install Time Module it was asking me to update my pip to newest, and I did.
I receive this error:

`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement time (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for time`

My python verstion is the latest. Python 3.11.0
Pip version : 22.3.1

It's all to date..
any ideias why?

Tried installing via CMD and pycharm packages additions.
Also updated python and pip. no sucess.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to install the time module, which is a built-in module in Python. You don't need to install it using pip. You should be able to use it in your code by simply importing it like `import time`

Answer (score -1):

The time module is part of Python's standard library. It's installed along with the rest of Python, and you don't need to (nor can you!) install it with pip.

Comment: The second part of this answer does not belong in an answer. Clarifications should be asked in comments to the original question.